# Fuentes disponibles en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7, fuentes

¿Alguien sabe que fuentes de letra puedo utilizar en una aplicación de Tkinter con Python 3?.

Answer (score 4):

Las fuentes utilizables en Tkinter dependen de las fuentes instaladas y disponibles en el sistema operativo de turno, puedes ver una lista completa usando el método `tkinter.font.families`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


root = tk.Tk()
for font in font.families():
    print(font)
```

Tkinter no dispone de ninguna herramienta preconstruida y SO-independiente que permita cargar una fuente externa desde un archivo. Aunque es posible hacer esto, lo es solo usando herramientas propias de cada sistema operativo y externas a Tkinter.

Comment: Gracias. Dios te bendiga.